# How to Evaluate Parameters in Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file, redirect

In a *nix shell, you can say:

```
foo `bar | baz`;
```

to redirect the output of `bar | baz` into the argument of `foo`.

How do you do this in a Windows batch file?

Comment: Have you checked out `for /f`?

Comment: @Gabe: Nope... I just looked at it, but I can't figure out how it works/helps...

Comment: The `FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ('command')` syntax provides a way to process the output of a command. You can then do something like `FOR /F %x IN ('bar | baz') DO foo %x`.

Comment: @Gabe: That's the answer I was looking for, thanks!! Post it as an answer please and I'll accept it. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ('command')` syntax provides a way to process the output of a command. You can then do something like `FOR /F %x IN ('bar | baz') DO foo %x`.

Comment: @Mehrdad: If I'm not mistaken, there's a difference regarding multi-line output, which you should be aware of. In *nix the entire output would be substituted for ``bar | baz`` and so `foo` would be invoked once. With `FOR /F` you'd get multiple invocations of `foo` for every line produced by `'bar | baz'`. If I'm wrong, I'm sure I'll be corrected.

Comment: @Andriy: Thanks for the heads-up, I'll remember that.

Comment: @Andriy: You are correct. However, it's so rare that one attemps to pass multiple lines in a command line argument that I didn't think it worth mentioning.